# How to use angular material inside angular JS custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I want to make a custom directive which should act like How zoom works in google sheets.

I want to display a toast message when user reaches certain zooming level.But I don't know how to use angular material inside custom directives.

Please provide a small examples

Comment: same way you use any other html or service in a directive. Please provide more specifics ... see [ask]

Comment: ng-model is a directive, ng-show is a directive md-toast is an angular material directive, you can use them all from your HTML or you can use custom made directives like [this](https://github.com/mvindahl/angular-pan-zoom) to control your zoom functions, try to create a plunkr for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.directive('myDirective', function($mdToast){
   return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       controllerAs: '$ctrl',
       controller: function(){
           this.myDirectiveAction = function(){
               $mdToast.showSimple('message');
           };
       };
   };
})
```

Comment: Thankyou So much Valery

Comment: Can we return html from this directive like: `<md-sidenav>...</md-sidenav>`?